# Дополнительное view перекрывает основное view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

У меня есть основное view где имеются кнопки и гугл карта.

```
 let maps = MapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapview = maps

        view.addSubview(mapview!)
```

И по изменению состояние пользователя , на основное view добавляются детали таким же образом

```
let new = ButtonView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        ButView = new
        view.addSubview(ButView!)
```

При добавление этих view , моя карта перекрывается слоями дополнительных view и я не могу сделать какие либо деиствия.

Comment: Создайте кастомную view которая будет добавленна на ваш основной view и эта view должна быть под вашей картой. И когда создаете новые элементы, добавляйте их не на основную view, а на ту, что вы создали.

Comment: а если добавлю view на view которая под картой , разве добавленные элементы не будут под картой

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать определенный View выше других, используя:

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)
```

Либо вы можете установить настройку для определенного View, для того, чтобы он не реагировал на касания.

```
someView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

UPD:
Попробуйте задавать размеры (или настроить лэйауты) для необходимых view чтобы они не перекрывали друг друга.

Comment: у меня все view должны реагировать на касания , я думаю когда я указываю frame для childview , он берет границы ViewController и перекрывает основное view

Comment: @ЧингизКуандык да, такое возможно. Лучше в данном случае задавать размеры для необходимого view.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в `x` и `y` аргументах при определении `frame` у создаваемой вами `ButtonView`. Вы создаёте новое вью в точке, где начинается главное, ещё и выставляя одинаковый размеры. Т.е. оно **должно** перекрывать, т.к. начинается в той же точке и имеет такой же размер.

Прошло 10 месяцев, но новым людям это помочь должно.